# Understanding how a Wifi Analyzer works on windows 10 with java

Tags: java, windows-10, wifi

I am trying to understand how a Wifi analyzer works. As i am currently doing a security project, i am required to check for Access Points for it's IP address and Mac Address of their BSSID.

Do i require any libraries to have/allow myself to have the same ability to scan for Networks and IP Address/Mac Addresses?

Or do i have to move into a different language such as C# as it is a windows environment

The project i am doing is an Evil Twin detection/warning. where

Tried calling system command "netsh wlan show profiles" & "netsh wlan show networks =Bssid" both outputs what i want except for the AP's IP Address

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Execute shell commands test");
        System.out.println();

        try {
            String cmd = "cmd /c netsh wlan show profiles ";
            System.out.println("Execute command: " + cmd); 
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            int result = p.waitFor();

            System.out.println("Process exit code: " + result);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Result: ");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "" ;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the IP Address of the AP just use `ipconfig` in cmd and read out the default gateway. Does not work if the ap does no dhcp, because the you get the IP address of the next router.

Comment: i see but i am finding all 'Other' AP's IP thus the only way i can find out in CMD is 'netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid' but now i want to save those information into a database for a wifi scanner , applications such as INSSID or acrylic wifi home

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: None of the window's commands for netsh will show the broadcasting IP addresses of the Access Point

Comment: What do you mean by the “broadcasting ip addresses”? A broadcast address is always the last address available in a network to send a packet to all clients. If you want the IP address on that the AP can be reached in the network, use `ipconfig`. Otherwise I really don’t get what you want. Maybe I am just too stupid, but if it’s possible post an example of the network configuration.

Comment: Hello SuperMario48! i have found a code from someone else's stack over flow question and is currently executing the said plan. Thank you so much for trying to help @SuperMario48  . It is all based off from the netsh wlan command.